# php array comperation, complete missing array locations

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
 $array1 = array('name', 'email', 'phone');
 $array2 = array('name' => 'John', 'phone' => '55-555-555');
```

I have created a HTML table from this two arrays, array1 is the table heads, and array2 is the td contents.

what happens now is that becouse array2 is missing a value (email in this case) I will get the phone data under the mail column. 
i would like to get this result:

```
 $array2 = array('name' => 'John', 'email' => ' ', 'phone' => '55-555-555');
```

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076323/php-compare-arrray1-with-array2-and-find-difference-then-fill-the-missing-value) answer, but it has two main problems:

1. the array keys desapear.
2. the `0` values are added at the end of the array and not in their original location.

Comment: *"I have created a table ..."* -- do you mean an HTML `<table>`?

Comment: yes, sorry HTML table.

Comment: @DavSev Did you see the answers?

Comment: yes i did, thank you. I am tring them.

Comment: Related: [how to set default value for array（php)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6032741/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source array is wrong. You need to have something like this:

```
$array1 = array('name' => '', 'email' => '', 'phone' => '');
```

And if you want to extend with the empty values, you can use:

```
$array2 = array('name' => 'John', 'phone' => '55-555-555');
```

The final array can be made by using [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

```
$array2 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

You will get this as output:

```
array('name' => 'John', 'email' => '', 'phone' => '55-555-555');
```

**Full Code**

```
$array1 = array('name' => '', 'email' => '', 'phone' => '');
$array2 = array('name' => 'John', 'phone' => '55-555-555');
$array2 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
var_export($array2);
```

**Output**

```
array (
  'name' => 'John',
  'email' => '',
  'phone' => '55-555-555',
)
```

**Demo: http://ideone.com/7zlab7**

---

**Better Explanation**

```
// Have a base array that has all the required fields.
$baseArr = array('name', 'email', 'phone', 'password');
// Get your array with the initial values, (without a few fields).
$myArray = array('name' => 'david', 'email' => 'aaa@aaa.aaa', 'phone'=> '123456789');
// Now make a new array on the fly with array_fill_keys using the baseArr
// and merge with the original user array.
$myArray = array_merge(array_fill_keys($baseArr, ''), $myArray);
// The resultant array will have all the fields.
print_r($myArray);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [name] => david
    [email] => aaa@aaa.aaa
    [phone] => 123456789
    [password] => 
)
```

**Demo: http://ideone.com/XLCMN9**

Comment: Any pointers on why this is downvoted will be helpful. Well I am happy to learn.

Comment: I cant get to empty the values in the `$array1` array, How can i do it so i will get the result you have published above?

Comment: @DavSev How can you do what?

Comment: Set all values to `' '` like you explaind on the second row. now i manage to get an assocciative array but all the keys have date. i tried to use `array_fill_keys` but it converts the array values into array keys!

Comment: @DavSev Yes, you should use `array_fill_keys`. That should work for you. And send the original array. What's wrong is happening in it?

Comment: What happens is as such: i have this array `array(5) {
  ["FIRST NAME"]=>
  string(3) "DAV"
  ["LAST NAME"]=>
  string(3) "SEV"
  ["PHONE"]=>
  string(10) "+123123123"
  ["MAIL"]=>
  string(11) "aaa@aaa.aaa"
  ["REFFER"]=>
  string(6) "REFFER"
}` after placing it in `array_fill_keys` i get the next array :  `array(5) {
  ["DAV"]=>
  string(3) ""
  ["SEV"]=>
  string(3) " "
  ["+123123123"]=>
  string(10) " "
  ["aaa@aaa.aaa"]=>
  string(11) " "
  ["REFFER"]=>
  string(6) " "
}` the values turns to the array keys... i want to mantain the original keys with `' '` value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127828/discussion-between-davsev-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP function [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to find out if the data array contains a value for the column you want to print.

Something like this:

```
$array1 = array('name', 'email', 'phone');
$array2 = array('name' => 'John', 'phone' => '55-555-555');

// Echo <table>, table header row etc here

// Print the data row
echo('<tr>');
foreach ($array1 as $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
        echo('<td>'.$array2[$key].'</td>');
    } else {
        echo('<td></td>');
    }
}
echo('</tr>');
```

You can use the same technique to fill the missing values in `$array2` (and keep the rendering code unchanged):

```
foreach ($array1 as $key) {
    if (! array_key_exists($key, $array2) {
        $array1[$key] = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Praveen Kumar's answer should be the accepted one, but here's another approach which also works:

```
$array_1 = array('name', 'phone', 'address');
$array_2 = array('name' => 'john', 'address' => 'street number');

foreach ($array_1 as $key) {
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $array_2)) {
        $array_2[$key] = '';
    }
}

var_export($array_2);
```

This will output the following result:

```
array ( 'name' => 'john', 'address' => 'street number', 'phone' => '' )
```